# Error while building a custom list adapter

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I am trying to create a custom Adapter based on a few examples, but I keep getting some errors that I can´t figure it out.

I will post the complete class and then I will point out the errors.

```
package br.com.agenciaeisberg.qm;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Usuário on 04/02/2015.
 */
public class HospitaisAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Hospitais> ListaHospitais;
    private Context context;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public HospitaisAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Hospitais> ListaHospitais) {
        this.ListaHospitais= ListaHospitais;
        this.context=context;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_hospital, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.pid= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pid);
            holder.nome= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome);
            holder.image= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imglotacao);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Hospitais item = (Hospitais) ListaHospitais.get(position);

        holder.pid.setText(item.getPid());
        holder.nome.setText(item.getNome());

        holder.image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.l_9_1));


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView pid;
        TextView nome;
        ImageView image;

    }
}
```

As for the errors

1 - It says it cannot resolve symbol on this :

```
private ArrayList<Hospitais> ListaHospitais;
    private Context context;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public HospitaisAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Hospitais> ListaHospitais) {
        this.ListaHospitais= ListaHospitais;
        this.context=context;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
```

I cannot understand what is happening.

2 - It cannot resolve the symbol listData

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }
```

3 - Cannot Resolve Method on this  getPid and getNome

```
holder.pid.setText(item.getPid());
holder.nome.setText(item.getNome());
```

Answer (score 1):

In `getCount()` and `getItem()` replace

```
listData
```

with

```
ListaHospitais
```

Check if class `Hospitais` has methods `getPid()` and `getNome()`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, `listData` is never defined anywhere, hence the "cannot resolve the symbol listData"